# Changing a specific byte in a file

Tags: java, android, file-io, byte

I am trying to write a java function that will change 1 byte in a large file. How can I read in and write to a specific address in a file with java on android? I have tried fis.read(byte b[], int off, int len) and I get a force close every time.

Comment: Show us your code and your logcat.

Answer (score 23):

Use [`RandomAccessFile`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/RandomAccessFile).

Kickoff example:

```
try (RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw")) {
    raf.seek(5); // Go to byte at offset position 5.
    raf.write(70); // Write byte 70 (overwrites original byte at this offset).
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help... I will try that in the morning. How would I read that byte before I overwrite it?

Comment: Just `byte b = raf.readByte();`.