# how can i play video from byte in android

Tags: android, encryption, android-videoview

I have video in my project. and for security i encrypt the video files which is working quite well.
but problem is that the

```
 **videoView.setVideoPath("/mnt/sdcard/intro_video.3gp");**
```

In this method I have to pass the file.(which is decrypted) 
so I am creating decrypted file on sdcard for path of file is that possible to pass bytes (which are decrypted) directly in video view. I am using Cipher for encrypt.

Here is my code for

```
 private void decryption()throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String filePath2 = path + "en/encVideo";

    String filePath3 = path + "de/decVideo";

    File decfile = new File(filePath3);


    if(!decfile.exists())
        decfile.createNewFile();

    File outfile = new File(filePath2);
    int read;

    FileInputStream encfis = new FileInputStream(outfile);
    Cipher decipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");

    decipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skey);
    FileOutputStream decfos = new FileOutputStream(decfile);
    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(decfos,decipher);   

    while((read=encfis.read()) != -1)
    {

        cos.write(read);
        cos.flush();
    }
    cos.close(); 
}
```

Comment: Hi @Youddh, I am looking for similar solution. Can you share the working code?

Comment: @user1444172 sorry as par my knowledge it's not possible, so i create file in sdcard (with change of some byte's) then i recharge to original byte to play it.(hear is the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4576388/changing-a-specific-byte-in-a-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you can do it. Since you are using VideoView, it would require specific headers and tail ends that suggest which format and how it is encoded etc. If you can figure out that I still doubt it can take raw file. Your best bet would be to create random file names while saving and passing that to the player.

Comment: ok thanks  but i fond another option for it i just replace specific byte of video then write it ...but as u say i have to create file. so can i create file in catch  and then play it.. is that possible.. my video size is less then 2 mb...

Comment: I suppose you can. Lets hope some one else answers. Make sure you get the permission right :)

Answer (score 3):

If streaming the video to a VideoView without an intermediary file to store the decrypted version is what you are looking for, then the answer is Yes you can do it. You need two main components: a streaming server such as a local http instance and [CipherInputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/CipherInputStream.html).